# Problem with two-finger swipes on my magic mouse. Is there any form of fix?

Tags: mouse

Recently, I've migrated from a strict Windows to a OSX environment.  I'm using the Magic Mouse as my pointing device and so far I've been satisfied.

The only problem that I am having is that I can not get my mouse to consistently recognize my two-finger swipes to swap between my full screen apps.  It does work but only occasionally.  Specifically, I have to swipe about 30 times before the screen will actually switch to the other application.  Also, I know that the mouse is partially picking up my gesture because the window will begin to barely transition, but I usually can't get the screen to shift any more than a couple inches on my 27" display.

This is unusable.

Are there any gesture sensitivity settings that I may be able to tweak, buried in some form of an initialization of configuration file?  Or, am I stuck and I'll have to simply avoid using this gesture?  I think this functionality would be very useful.  For now, however, it's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also suggests [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/), a fork of [Multiclutch](http://wcrawford.org/2008/02/28/everytime-i-think-about-you-i-touch-my-cell/), which allows you to remap a tons of multi-touch gestures.

Moreover the program allows for windows snapping (a là Windows 7), and keyboard shortcuts.

It's definitely worth a try.

Comment: Wow, this has helped tremendously.  BetterTouchTool contains a screen that allows the user to visualize there touches on the Magic Mouse.  When I opened it, I quickly saw my problem with the two-finger swipe-- my skinny little fingers were registering as one big finger!  Thanks Gio

Answer (score 1):

Try this little utility: http://www.magicprefs.com/

It allows you to override mouse gestures, map them to your own actions, etc.
It also has a graphical view to show you what you're doing, which can be very useful in figuring out what you're doing wrong.